# How to delete all files in google storage folder using python

Tags: python

I have google cloud storage bucket path stored in one variable called GS_PATH 
example of google cloud storage path is gs://test/one/
Under this i have few more folders and files.

How can i delete all under gs://test/one/ path using python code

Thanks,

Arjun

Answer (score 3):

There is an API to do this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

my_storage = storage.Client()
bucket = my_storage.get_bucket('test')
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='one/')
for blob in blobs:
    blob.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-python for reference.

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')

blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='folder_prefix/')

for blob in blobs:
    blob.delete()
```